# Google sheets Conditional Formatting not applying to whole range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I've got a Sheet.
And I've put some conditional formatting in it.
Basically I want it to highlight the row red of the end column says Not Built

The condition works fine, but for some reason instead of highlighting the whole row, it only highlights the first column.
[image]

In My screenshot i've set the range as L7:N (it's Actually A7:N, but I changed it to L to fit in the screenshot)

As you can see it's highlighting the rows where column O says Not Built but for some reason it's only highlighting Column L instead of Columns L to N

I Could create a rule for each Column, but that just seems silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to lock the formula with `$` like:

```
=$O$7:$O="Not Built"
```